# Eigen values and vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra

$A:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is a 2 by 2 matrix whose eigen values are 2/3 and 9/5. Prove that there exists a non zero vector v such that |Av|=|v|.

It’s not given that A is symmetric. So I can not conclude that A is positive definite. How do I proceed?? Please help.

Comment: what norm are you using for $Av$ and $v$ ?

Comment: Euclidean norm in R^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Let $S$ be the unit sphere $\{\|x\| = 1\}$. Define $T : S \to \mathbb R$ by $T(x) = \|Ax\|$.

- S is a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (because you're using the Euclidean norm , the unit sphere is connected).
- $T$ is a continuous map (composition of continuous maps).
- Thus $T(S)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R$, hence an interval.
- That interval contains $\frac 23$ and $\frac 95$, so it also contains $1$.

(Complete any unknown details)

Answer (score 2):

Call $v_1$ and $v_2$ the eigenvectors referred to the two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2/3$ and $\lambda_2 = 9/5$. Also, you can take them with unit norm.

$\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$, so every vector can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors.
$$
Av = A(\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) = \alpha \lambda_1v_1 + \beta \lambda_2v_2 
$$
You want $|Av|^2 = |v|^2  $, so we compute the squared norm
$$
|Av|^2 = |\alpha \lambda_1v_1 + \beta \lambda_2v_2|^2 \\
=\alpha^2 \lambda_1^2  + \beta^2 \lambda_2^2 +2\alpha\beta\lambda_1\lambda_2 \langle v_1,v_2\rangle 
$$
$$
|v|^2 = |\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2|^2
=\alpha^2   + \beta^2 +2\alpha\beta\langle v_1,v_2\rangle
$$
You can then prove that a solution for $(\alpha,\beta)$ exists for
$$
\alpha^2 \lambda_1^2  + \beta^2 \lambda_2^2 +2\alpha\beta\lambda_1\lambda_2 \langle v_1,v_2\rangle =
\alpha^2   + \beta^2 +2\alpha\beta\langle v_1,v_2\rangle
$$
for example, by putting $\beta=1$ and proving that the discriminant of the second degree equation is positive.